# Visual Studio 2013 - How User Data is Persisted and Extended with the Web App Template

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

When I create an ASP.NET web app, the solution comes with an **Account** folder in the Views folder, in which there are several files related to the Account (such as change password, login, register etc.) In the **Register.cshtml** page, I want to be able to add to extra fields to the form - first and last name.

So in the **Register.cshtml** file, I've added the following:

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Surname, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Surname, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

Then also in the Models/**AccountViewModels.cs** file, I've added this:

```
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Surname")]
        public string Surname { get; set; }
```

But my question is, where is all this information being recorded? Basically, once the user has created an account and logged in, in the nav bar it would say: *Hello [emailaddress]!*

But what I want it to say is *Hello [Name] [Surname] !*

in the **_LoginPartial.cshtml** file:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li>
            @Html.ActionLink("Hello " + User.Identity.GetUserName() + "!", "Index", "Manage", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { title = "Manage" })
        </li>
        <li><a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a></li>
    </ul>
```

**User.Identity.GetUserName()** is the method which is returning the user email address at the moment. So I'll need to add additional methods for returning the first and last name of the user. However, I haven't been able to figure out where this information is stored so I can modify it.

Answer (score 0):

[MSDN has an example](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/16/customizing-profile-information-in-asp-net-identity-in-vs-2013-templates.aspx) of how to do this. Generally, this information isn't stored directly with the login data. With database normalization, which is a design principle that states how schema design should focus around the relation of the data within a table, data such as first and last name would be stored seperately since it doesn't directly relate to the username (in this case email) and the credentials used to login. His/her personal details don't directly relate to the information used to login so they occur separately. In ASP.Net Identity and the older ASP.Net Membership systems, this is done via a user profile that can be customized.

Answer (score 0):

I'll keep it brief.

First, the ASP.NET web app template hooks in [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx), which in turn stores the information about the user in a data base. By default it uses the following (web.config):

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-YourApplicationName-20141015014521.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-UserAccountTest-20141015014521;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

This means SQL Server CE out of the box, but you can configure everything to suite your needs and liking, including the name of the database. The mdf file created is located in the App_Data folder (turn on Show All Files in the Solution Explorer). Have look at it using the Server Explorer (just double-click the mdf in the Solution Explorer), and you'll see that especially the AspNetUsers table contains some interesting stuff.

Second, there are different ways you can expand the identity information. This "Web App" template uses Microsoft's [Katana](http://katanaproject.codeplex.com/) implementation of [OWIN](http://owin.org/), which in turn kicks in from the following (Startup.cs):

```
[assembly: OwinStartupAttribute(typeof(YourNamespace.Startup))]
namespace YourNamespace
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            ConfigureAuth(app);
        }
    }
}
```

... Which as you can see points to the `ConfigureAuth` class (in Startup.Auth.cs in the App_Start folder), but more importantly for this context, consider the `AccountController` constructors:

```
public AccountController()
            : this(new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()))) {}

public AccountController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager) {
    UserManager = userManager;
}
```

As you can see, they rig both the `ApplicationDbContext` (for Entity Framework) and the `ApplicationUser` class for the `UserManager`. The `ApplicationUser` is one extension point available for you when you want to add fields and data to the user. Have a look at what it says:

```
// You can add profile data for the user by adding more properties to your ApplicationUser class, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=317594 to learn more.
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser {}
```

However, if you just try to add some properties (which is exactly what you should do):

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public String Surname { get; set; }
    public String FamilyName { get; set; }
}
```

... At this point, you will run into trouble if the identity data base has already been created and get a YSOD:

> The model backing the 'ApplicationDbContext' context has changed since
>   the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to
>   update the database (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238269).

Following the instructions in the link, you enable "Code First Migrations". This creates a new folder for you named Migrations, in which the following code can be found (Configuration.cs):

```
public Configuration() {
    AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
    ContextKey = "UserAccountTest.Models.ApplicationDbContext";
}
```

(Also, note the seed method in this class, which can come in handy later on.)

For now, set `AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true`, update the database (Update-Database in the Packet Manager Console) and then run again. Now, register another user and then look at the identity table once more; you'll find that the columns "Surname" and "FamilyName" have been added to the AspNetUsers table.

(Now, this is all a simplification. As mentioned by Mark Fitzpatrick in his answer, at the database level the kind of information we are dealing with here is not usually associated with the user identity, and hence should preferably be stored separately.)

Next, have a look inside the `Register` action (HttpPost) of the `AccountController`, where it says:

```
var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.UserName };
```

To map the data from your altered form to the `ApplicationUser`, and ultimately persist values to the database, you need to change it to the following:

```
var user = new ApplicationUser() {
    UserName = model.UserName,
    Surname = model.Surname,
    FamilyName = model.Name
};
```

Now, the next time you register a user, the values submitted will also be persisted.

Also in the `AccountController`, the action `Login` (HttpPost) is responsible for calling the `UserManager` to fetch user data upon logging in, so that part is already taken care of (again via Entity Framework):

```
var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.UserName, model.Password);
```

And then (indirectly):

```
UserManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
```

Now, before we move on and tie this all together, there are a few things I feel I should mention. First of all, the _LoginPartial.cshtml in it's out-of-the-box state shows examples of *bad practices*. In my opinion, it should not contain such logic as `@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)`, and second, when displaying information such as the user name the information should be stored in a view model. I.e. the direct link between the view and the `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity` is not to my liking.

What I usually tend to do is to create a child action that decides what information to display depending on whether the user is logged on or not, and render it with `@Html.RenderAction()`. Alas, there are other viable options as well, but in that case it would fall upon the controller to then populate the view model with user information straight out of the ApplicationUser or some other domain model.

This all being said, if you really wanted to treat this name information as a "claim" (the default `IIdentity` implementation here is a `[ClaimsIdentity][4]`), and just to wrap things up here, you could do something like adding claims to the `ClaimsIdentity` created by the `UserManager` above:
    identity.AddClaims(new[] {
        new Claim("Surname", user.Surname), new Claim("FamilyName", user.FamilyName)
    });

Then, you could create an extension method to help in retrieving the information:

```
using System;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Security.Principal;

namespace YourNameSpace {

    public static class IdentityExtensions {

        public static string GetFullName(this IIdentity identity) {
            if (identity == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("identity");
            var claimsIdentity = identity as ClaimsIdentity;
            if (claimsIdentity == null)
                return null;
            var surname = Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IdentityExtensions.FindFirstValue(claimsIdentity, "Surname");
            var familyName = Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IdentityExtensions.FindFirstValue(claimsIdentity, "FamilyName");

            return surname + " " + familyName;
        }

    }

}
```

Finally, in your otherwise untouched _LoginPartial.cshtml, you could change User.Identity.GetUserName() and instead call your new extension, like so:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Hello " + User.Identity.GetFullName() + "!", "Manage", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { title = "Manage" })
```

... Resulting in the users full name being displayed on the page each time they log on successfully.